# gcloud filters regex inconsistency

Tags: gcloud

When I run the same flavor of command on the compute instances it works correctly

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter='name~mysql'
```

However, when I ran this command

```
gcloud dataproc clusters list --filter='clusterName ~ dev'
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Could not parse the filter: ParserException:errors {
  line: 1
  column: 13
  message: "syntax error"
  token: "~"
}
```

Any idea why the filter behaves this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--filter` flag is a single filtering flag which can be interpreted on client side or server side. In

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter='name~mysql'
```

case it is interpreted on client side. If you add `--log-http` you will see that filter expression is never sent in any api requests. On the other hand

```
gcloud dataproc clusters list --filter='clusterName~dev' --log-http
```

will show:

`==== request start ====
uri: https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT/regions/global/clusters?filter=%27clusterName%7Edev%27&alt=json&pageSize=100
method: GET
== headers start ==
...`

The dataproc backend api here is not able to handle same filtering syntax. See dataproc api documentation on filter: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/list

According to that documentation you can do

```
gcloud dataproc clusters list --filter='clusterName=dev'
```

Regardless the `--filter='clusterName~dev'` syntax should not be producing error, and should be reported as a bug here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you asked: why does it behave that way? Because in the former case, the filtering is done client-side (in accordance with `gcloud topic filters`) and in the latter case, the filtering is done server-side.

We'll investigate whether they can be brought into agreement.

Comment: Thank you. I have filed a bug #37658729. For now, I will workaround this using grep.